# reading a list of objects that is not an array object

Tags: angular

It seems that there is some bug in the process, because when I receive an object that is not an array and I generate the log the result is shown correctly, but when I generate the log JSON.stringify(editor) generates a list of objects, what is the explanation for that?

```
    editar(editor: Pessoa) {
    if (typeof editor === 'object' && !Array.isArray(editor)) {
      console.log('value is an object');
    } else if (Array.isArray(editor)) {
      console.log('The value is an array');
    } else {
      console.log('The value is neither an object nor an array');
    }
    // let teste = editor;
    console.log('----------------------editor----------------------');
    console.log(editor);    
    console.log('----------------------JSON.stringify(editor)----------------------');
    console.log(JSON.stringify(editor));
   
  }
```

the object in the editor parameter derives from an object of type array.

but in the call I pass an object:

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let c of editores">
            <tr>
              <td>{{ c.editorsType?.name }}</td>
              <td>{{ c.fullName }}</td>
              <td>{{ c.countries?.nameEN }}</td>
              <td>{{ c.universidade }}</td>
              <td>{{ c.email }}</td>
              <td class="text-center">{{c.orcid}}</td>
              <!-- Adicionados botões de editar e excluir -->
              <td><button class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary" (click)="editar(c)"
                  [disabled]="c.pessoaId <= 2">Edit</button></td>
              <td><button class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary" (click)="excluir(c)"
                  [disabled]="c.pessoaId <= 2">Delete</button></td>
            </tr>
          </ng-container>


    Package                         Version
---------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect       0.1601.4
@angular-devkit/build-angular   16.1.4
@angular-devkit/core            16.1.4
@angular-devkit/schematics      16.1.4
@angular/cli                    16.1.4
@nguniversal/builders           16.1.1
@nguniversal/express-engine     16.1.1
@schematics/angular             16.1.4
rxjs                            7.8.1
typescript                      5.1.6
```

Answer (score 1):

Try keyvalue pipe:

```
<div *ngFor="let c of editores | keyvalue">
    {{c.key}}:{{c.value}}
</div>
```

https://angular.io/api/common/KeyValuePipe

Comment: I didn't get to test it, but why would this approach work? I would just like an explanation as to why it doesn't work. In theory it should work, or is it just a bug?